# Unable to connect from ASP.NET Core Web API to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to connect to a PostgreSQL database from ASP.NET Core Web API.

Below is the repository: [https://github.com/ashok-login/Carsties.git](https://stackoverflow.com)

Of course, I'm using Docker to connect to PostgreSQL. Inside the Web API project, I've created two classes `Auction` and `Item` to get them created as database tables.

Here is the definition for your quick reference:

```
namespace AuctionService.Entities
{
    public class Auction
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int? ReservePrice { get; set; } = 0;
        public string Seller { get; set; }
        public string Winner { get; set; }
        public int? SoldAmount { get; set; }
        public int? CurrentHighBid { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public DateTime AuctionEnd { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; } = Status.Live;
        public Item Item { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace AuctionService.Entities
{
    [Table("Items")]
    public class Item
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public int Mileage { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        // Navigation properties
        public Auction Auction { get; set; }
        public Guid AuctionId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Below is the enum.

```
namespace AuctionService.Entities
{
    public enum Status
    {
        Live,
        Finished,
        ReserveNotMet
    }
}
```

Once after the database is updated successfully using Package Manager console, when trying to view the table data, I get this error:

> Executed SQL statement: SELECT Id, ReservePrice, Seller, Winner, SoldAmount, CurrentHighBid, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, AuctionEnd, Status FROM Auctions
> Error Source: Npgsql
> Error Message: 42P01: relation "auctions" does not exist

Regards,
Ashok Kumar K.

When searched in Google, I understood something like I've to use lowercase letters while creating tablenames, and column-names. But, the above two classes were created as per Instructor's guidance, and he has not used lowercase letters for table-names, or column-names.

Hence, I've tried to learn from [one another article](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/06/23/net-6-connect-to-postgresql-database-with-entity-framework-core#download-api). I'm experiencing the same issue in this new project also -

> Relation "users" does not exist.

Looks like I'm missing something. Can someone please suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: could you show the SQl and your table ?